# Why do I get 0 for Count([Field]) when null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
Select [Field], count([Field]) as Counts
from [Table_Name]
group by [Field]
```

The results look like the following:

```
[Field] [Counts]
Type1   100
Type2   100
Type3   100
Type4   100
Null    0
```

However when I count on a Key or any other field than the field I'm grouping on I get the actual count of rows with [Field] Null. Why is that?

```
Select [Field], count([Other]) as Counts
from [Table_Name]
group by [Field]
```

Result:

```
[Field] [Counts]
Type1   100
Type2   100
Type3   100
Type4   100
Null    100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `COUNT` works. When you specify column `NULL` values are eliminated from calculation. And because your `COUNT` is set on the same column as `GROUP BY`, you receive `0` for `NULL` group - all values you're counting are `NULL` and they are all skipped.

You can make it work with following code:

```
Select [Field], count(ISNULL([Field], 0)) as Counts
from [Table_Name]
group by [Field]
```

Or maybe simpler:

```
Select [Field], count(*) as Counts
from [Table_Name]
group by [Field]
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation...i was not able to put those in words.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to experiment with my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d753e/1).

As currently configured (you can make any changes you want) for the following data:

```
FIELD1  OTHER
AA      (null)
BB         O1
BB         O2
AA         A1
(null)     N3
(null)  (null)
```

the following query that incorporates all three COUNT options for this particular table:

```
SELECT [Field1], COUNT([Field1]) [Fields], 
                 COUNT([Other]) [Others], 
                 COUNT(*) [Records]
FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY [Field1]
```

produces the following results:

```
FIELD1  FIELDS  OTHERS  RECORDS
(null)     0        1      2
AA         2        1      2
BB         2        2      2
```